# Swift like array class behavior with subscript

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, subscript

I did implement class which use subscript and return objects like following:

```
class PlacesSet {
  ...
  subscript(i: Int) -> Place {
      get {
          return stored[i];
      }
      set {
          stored[i] = newValue;
      }
  }
}
```

But when I try to pass it as array in some cocoa function it returns error.
Should I implement some protocol and missing methods? And is it possible to do in general?

Comment: Which error? runtime or compilation? Post an example of code that fails

Comment: it says that PlacesSet not type of NSArray and if I add :NSArray to that
I'm getting "overriding indexed subscript with incompatible type (Int) -> Place"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing a subscript doesn't magically turn a class or struct into an array, so you can't pass an instance of `PlaceSet` where a swift array or `NSArray` is expected.

What you can do is implement a method in your class that returns an `NSArray`:

```
func toArray() -> NSArray {
    ...
}
```

or a property if you prefer:

```
var asArray: NSArray { return ... }
```

If you really want your class to behave like an `NSArray`, then make `PlaceSet` a subclass of it - but it's something that I don't recommend. The same *cannot* be done with a swift array, because it's a struct, hence it doesn't support inheritance.

Comment: it may work but, when I add confirm class to protocol NSArray and whether implement asArray or not 
error is still there "overriding indexed subscript with incompatible type (Int) -> Place"
So i can't use asArray with subscript so far, but in need of both behaviors

Comment: Sorry it's not clear what you mean - pls post the code where the error happens, without that it's impossible to figure out what's wrong in your code

Comment: if i do thing like:
"mapKitView.addAnnotations(navigation.places)"
error that it's not subtype of NSArray, even with asArray var
but if i add :NSArray to class. error is "overriding indexed subscript with incompatible type (Int) -> Place"
on subscript line

Comment: That doesn't help much, because I don't know what `navigation.places` is